# Django Form specify table to use for field

Tags: django

For the field `cast` in the `Movie` object I want to use the table `Cast_movie` generated which is  `movies_cast_movie` instead i get an error that **movies_movie_cast doesn't exist**

movies/models.py
from django.db import models
from .models import *

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    cast = models.ManyToManyField('Cast_movie', related_name='cast_movies')

class Cast_movie(models.Model):
    movie = models.ForeignKey('movies.movie', on_delete = models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    cast = models.ForeignKey('casts.cast', on_delete = models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    role =  models.ForeignKey('casts.role', on_delete = models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.cast
```

How do i specify the table to use?

Comment: Can you perhaps explain all the relationship fields you have? Specifically the ForeignKey's in the Cast_movie model.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set table name of the `ManyToMany` relationship, you can use `through` option, and since there are more than 2 relationship in your `through` model (`Cast_movie`), you have to choose only two of them by `through_fields` option.

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    cast = models.ManyToManyField('casts.cast', through="Cast_movie", through_fields=("movie", "cast",),  related_name='cast_movies',)
    
class Cast_movie(models.Model):
    movie = models.ForeignKey('movies.movie', on_delete = models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    cast = models.ForeignKey('casts.cast', on_delete = models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    role =  models.ForeignKey('casts.role', on_delete = models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table="whatever_name_you_want_for_your_table"
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.cast
```

Here, we set the `Cast_movie` model as our manytomany relationship table, and we set the table name using the db_table field.

Comment: I get this error **movies.Cast_movie: The model is used as an intermediate model by 'movies.Movie.cast', but it does not have a foreign key to 'Movie' or 'Cast_movie'.
movies.Movie.cast: 'Cast_movie.cast' is not a foreign key to 'Cast_movie'.** ?

Comment: Yea I get it. The cast field on the Movie model was using `Cast_movie` but I think you intend to use `casts.cast` right? I edited the answer, can you try again please?

Comment: Thanks, no error.  But the field isn't displayed?

Comment: Which field is not displayed? Also, can you please provide queries you make? So that I can understand what you want to achieve more clearly.

Comment: the `cast` field.  There should be a select field?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. Can you provide more details in the question, what you mean by select field, what you expect and what you get

Comment: manytomanyfield should show a select multiple element.  https://i.imgur.com/6wxbGqa.png , There is no element displayed to select cast.